# Delimiter to use for parsing negative numbers

Tags: java, regex

I want to parse a String using `split` to find integers (positive and negative). For example, `dfgs#&-6d5.,b-dgj895-9-8` would turn into the array `[-6, 5, 895, -9, -8]`.

In English, the regex would be:

1. Characters that are not digits
2. Characters that are not dashes followed by digits
3. Zero-width characters that are followed by a dash that is followed by a digit

These are the separate components, but I do not know how to join them together:

1. `\D+`
2. `[^-(?=[0-9])]`
3. `(?=-[0-9]+)`

Comment: What have u tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`split` is obviously not the appropriate tool to obtain the result you want. However to do it with `split` you can use this pattern:

```
String[] nbs = text.split("(?>[^-0-9]+|-(?![0-9]))+|(?=-[0-9])");
```

But you need to remove empty results after (that can be at the begining or at the end, depending of the string).

Answer (score 2):

It really doesn't sound like `split` is what you want. Using a [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)/[`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) seems to be more in line with what you're trying to do:

```
String text = "dfgs#&-6d5.,bdgj895-9-8";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+").matcher(text);
while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

```
-6
5
895
-9
-8
```

You can use a `List<String>` to store the matches.

Comment: No, I want to know how to do it with split.

Comment: @JoelA.Christophel I want to know how to boil water with a hammer.